# Timestamp "yesterday" but with specific hour range

Tags: sql-server

This is my Query - 
it will retrieve yesterday's data - every day - but I need a time window added.
I am a SQL newbie and know almost nothing, so any and all help greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT QB.vw_Device.DeviceName + '-' + QB.vw_Item.ItemId AS [Station-ItemID],
                                       QB.vw_PocketAccess.TransactionQuantity AS Qty,
                                       QB.vw_PocketAccess.PocketAccessDateTime AS [Time Stamp]
FROM QB.vw_PocketAccess
INNER JOIN QB.vw_TransactionType ON QB.vw_PocketAccess.TransactionTypeKey = QB.vw_TransactionType.TransactionTypeKey
INNER JOIN QB.vw_User ON QB.vw_PocketAccess.UserKey = QB.vw_User.UserKey
AND QB.vw_PocketAccess.DataStoreKey = QB.vw_User.DataStoreKey
INNER JOIN QB.vw_Item ON QB.vw_PocketAccess.ItemKey = QB.vw_Item.ItemKey
AND QB.vw_PocketAccess.DataStoreKey = QB.vw_Item.DataStoreKey
INNER JOIN QB.vw_Device ON QB.vw_Item.DataStoreKey = QB.vw_Device.DataStoreKey
AND QB.vw_PocketAccess.DeviceKey = QB.vw_Device.DeviceKey
INNER JOIN QB.vw_ItemClass ON QB.vw_PocketAccess.DataStoreKey = QB.vw_ItemClass.DataStoreKey
AND QB.vw_Item.ItemClass = QB.vw_ItemClass.ItemClass
AND QB.vw_Item.ClientKey = QB.vw_ItemClass.ClientKey
WHERE QB.vw_PocketAccess.PocketAccessDateKey = Cast(Convert(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(DD, -1, SYSDATETIME()),112) AS INT)
```

I'm looking for a window between midnight and 9:00 am, and the field PocketAccessDateTime is a datetime format.

I understand I'm using PocketAccessDateKey as my 'yesterday' filter, I just don't know how to make this work.

sincerest thanks,
Larry

Comment: Dear lord, what's that monster? No offence, but.. O_o

Comment: none taken - it takes several tables to get the output I need...I didn't create it, I just use it.

Comment: But you could at least bring it in a readable form. That's what he meant. Or even better, cut out details we don't need to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some funky [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)/[`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) trickery:

```
Where
    QB.vw_PocketAccess.PocketAccessDateTime >=
          DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010102',SYSDATETIME()),
                                   '2001-01-01T00:00:00') AND
    QB.vw_PocketAccess.PocketAccessDateTime <
          DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010102',SYSDATETIME()),
                                   '2001-01-01T09:00:00')
```

Will find rows where `PocketAccessDateKey` is greater (or equal)<sup>1</sup> to midnight yesterday and is also less than 09:00am yesterday.

The trickery is in picking appropriate constant datetime values that express the relationship we desire to find. Here I'm arbitrarily using some particular dates from January 2001.

---

<sup>1</sup> When working with continuous data such as datetime values, you usually want to work with semi-open intervals, such as here where I'm using an *inclusive* start datetime and an *exclusive* end datetime. It avoids many double counting issues and/or having to compute quite complex endpoint values.

Comment: DateKey doesn't have the time stamp, only date - and is apparently required. When I save the query, I get a "Date Filter should contain valid DateKey values" error.  So, I think I need DateKey to get the date filter, and maybe incorporate PocketAccessDateTime to get the time values ?  Or do I manually edit the script each day for "yesterday" ?  thanks bunches !

Comment: The datetime values I've shown shouldn't need editing. It make help if you could show some sample data for these columns so that we can see what you're trying to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

With PocketAccessDateKey being a datetime you can convert this to a string containing both date and time and compare it with strings containing yesterday plus the desired times:

```
WHERE 
  Replace(Convert(VARCHAR(19), QB.vw_PocketAccess.PocketAccessDateKey, 120), '-', '') -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss to yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss
  BETWEEN
  Convert(VARCHAR(19), DateAdd(DD, -1, SYSDATETIME()), 112) || ' 00:00:00'
  AND
  Convert(VARCHAR(19), DateAdd(DD, -1, SYSDATETIME()), 112) || ' 09:00:00'
```

Comment: a `varchar(8)` will *never* contain something of the form `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)` as your comment indicates. It will contain something of the form `yyyy-mm-`

Comment: Yes, that was nonsense. I've corrected my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: And it's still wrong. 120 writes 'yyyy-mm-dd' whereas 112 writes 'yyyymmdd'. I have corrected my answer once more.